how to test next-js dynamic import component with jest?
i want to test dynamic import component with jest, but every time i get error "   Unable to find an element", i have tried to mock dynamic import with different ways, and also tried to increase test time out but nothing works for me yet.
here is how i imported the component:
"use client";
import React, { FC, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch } from "../../../../redux/store";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useTranslation, i18n } from "next-i18next";
import { hasMemberPermission } from "../../../../utils/utils";

import { fetchBountyList } from "../../../../redux/features/getBountyListSlice";
import { fetchAssetsList } from "../../../../redux/features/getAssetListDetails";
import { InternalPageTitle } from "../../../internalPagesCommons/ui";
import { PremiumSubscription } from "../../../ui/reusable/premiumSubscriptionBox";

import TLSpinner from "../../../ui/reusable/tlSpinner/TLSpinner";
import Spinner from "../../../ui/reusable/spinner/Spinner";
import {
  EngagementSubscriptionSkeleton,
  ListTableSkeleton,
} from "../../../internalPagesCommons/costumSkelton";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// import EngagementList from "./../engagementList";
// import EngagementSubscription from "./../engagementSubscription";

const Bounty: FC<{
  accessByUnitTest?: boolean;
  assetsByUnitTest?: any;
  saveData?: any;
  bountiesByUnitTest?: any;
}> = ({
  accessByUnitTest = false,
  assetsByUnitTest,
  saveData = () => {
    return;
  },
  bountiesByUnitTest,
}) => {
  const EngagementList = useMemo(
    () =>
      dynamic(() => import("./../engagementList"), {
        ssr: false,
        loading: () => <ListTableSkeleton title="AllBounty" />,
      }),
    []
  );
  const EngagementSubscription = useMemo(
    () =>
      dynamic(() => import("./../engagementSubscription"), {
        ssr: false,
        loading: () => <EngagementSubscriptionSkeleton />,
      }),
    []
  );

and here the test file:
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import {
  findByTestId,
  fireEvent,
  render,
  screen,
  waitFor,
} from "../../../../../testUtils/testUtils";
import { useRouter } from "../../../../../__mocks__/nextRouter.mock";
import { store } from "../../../../../redux/store";
import { useTranslation } from "../../../../../__mocks__/next-i18next.mock";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Reports from "..";
import Bounty from "..";
import BountyDetailsComponent from "../BountyDetails";
import { setPermissionsByUnitTest } from "../../../../../utils/utils";

jest.mock("next/router", () => ({
  useRouter: () => useRouter({ route: "/organization-setting" }),
}));

jest.mock("next-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => useTranslation(),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe("Member bounty", () => {
  it("Should not be able to access bounties", async () => {
    setPermissionsByUnitTest(["NONE"]);

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Bounty accessByUnitTest={true} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const bountyContainer = screen.queryByTestId("bounty-container");
    await waitFor(() => expect(bountyContainer).toBeNull());
  });

  it("Should be able to access & create bounty", async () => {
    setPermissionsByUnitTest(["can_access_bounties_list", "can_create_bounty"]);
    const saveData = jest.fn();
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Bounty
          accessByUnitTest={true}
          assetsByUnitTest={{
            assets: [
              {
                name: "other",
                uuid: "17fb0eba-0f6e-47e0-9b2a-23ae4d87039x",
                platform: "OTHER",
              },
            ],
          }}
          saveData={saveData}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
    user.setup();
    const createBountyButton = await screen.findByTestId("create-program");
    await user.click(createBountyButton);
    const inputName = await screen.findByTestId("inputName");
    await user.click(inputName);
    await user.type(inputName, "bounty by unit test");
    const inputWebsite = await screen.findByTestId("inputWebsite");
    await user.click(inputWebsite);
    await user.type(inputWebsite, "website by unit test");
    const inputTwitter = await screen.findByTestId("inputTwitter");
    await user.click(inputTwitter);
    await user.type(inputTwitter, "twitter by unit test");
    const datePickerInput = await screen.findByPlaceholderText("Select a date");
    await user.click(datePickerInput);
    fireEvent.keyDown(datePickerInput, { key: "Enter", charCode: 13 });
    const assets = screen.getAllByRole("combobox");
    await user.click(assets[0]);
    await user.type(assets[0], "other");
    fireEvent.keyDown(assets[0], { key: "Enter", charCode: 13 });
    const bountyEligible = screen.getAllByRole("combobox");
    await user.click(bountyEligible[1]);
    await user.type(bountyEligible[1], "Eligible");
    fireEvent.keyDown(bountyEligible[1], { key: "Enter", charCode: 13 });
    const addAssetButton = await screen.findByTestId(
      "add-asset-button-for-program"
    );
    await user.click(addAssetButton);
    const nextButton = await screen.findByTestId("next-program");
    await user.click(nextButton);
    const programTypes = screen.getAllByRole("combobox");
    await user.click(programTypes[2]);
    await user.type(programTypes[2], "Public");
    fireEvent.keyDown(programTypes[2], { key: "Enter", charCode: 13 });
    await user.click(nextButton);
    const submitProgram = await screen.findByTestId("submit-program");
    await user.click(submitProgram);
    const newDate = new Date();

    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(saveData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        title: "bounty by unit test",
        start_date: `${newDate.getFullYear()}-${
          newDate.getMonth() + 1 > 9
            ? String(newDate.getMonth() + 1)
            : "0" + String(newDate.getMonth() + 1)
        }-${
          newDate.getDate() > 9
            ? String(newDate.getDate())
            : "0" + String(newDate.getDate())
        }`,
        website: "website by unit test",
        twitter: "twitter by unit test",
        targets: [
          {
            asset: "17fb0eba-0f6e-47e0-9b2a-23ae4d87039x",
            bounty: {
              critical_severity: "800",
              high_severity: "500",
              low_severity: "100",
              max_critical_severity: "900",
              max_high_severity: "600",
              max_low_severity: "200",
              max_medium_severity: "400",
              medium_severity: "300",
            },
            is_eligible_for_bounty: false,
          },
        ],
        is_public: true,
      })
    );
  });

  it("Should be able to access bounty details", async () => {
    const saveData = jest.fn();

    setPermissionsByUnitTest([
      "can_access_bounties_list",
      "can_create_bounty",
      "can_access_program_details",
      "can_access_program_security",
      "can_access_program_reports",
      "can_access_program_scope",
      "can_access_program_attachments",
      "can_access_program_settings",
    ]);

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BountyDetailsComponent
          uuid="57fb0eba-0f6e-47e0-9b2a-23ae4d87039p"
          accessByUnitTest={true}
          programByUnitTest={{
            uuid: "57fb0eba-0f6e-47e0-9b2a-23ae4d87039p",
            title: "Test unit test",
            name: "Test unit test",
            status: "Active",
            range_of_bounty: "100-800",
            phase_description: "Test",
            vulnerabilities_reports: [],
            severity_of_findings: [],
            policy: "<p>DON'T REMOVE</p>",
            type: "BUGBOUNTYPROGRAM",
            program_image: null,
            targets: [
              {
                uuid: "57fb0eba-0f6e-47e0-9b2a-23ae4d87039x",
                asset: {
                  platform: "OTHER",
                  description: "By unit test",
                  target: "www.unit.com",
                },
              },
            ],
          }}
          saveData={saveData}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
    user.setup();
    const tabs = await screen.findAllByRole("tab");
    await user.click(tabs[1]);
    await user.click(tabs[2]);
    await user.click(tabs[3]);
    await user.click(tabs[4]);
    await user.click(tabs[5]);
    const programName = await screen.findByTestId("ProgramName");
    await user.click(programName);
    await user.type(programName, "Test unit test");
    const programDescription = await screen.findByTestId("Description");
    await user.click(programDescription);
    await user.type(programDescription, "Test description unit test");
    const inputWebsite = await screen.findByTestId("Website");
    await user.click(inputWebsite);
    await user.type(inputWebsite, "website by unit test");
    const inputTwitter = await screen.findByTestId("Twitter/X");
    await user.click(inputTwitter);
    await user.type(inputTwitter, "twitter by unit test");
    const saveUpdateProgramButton = await screen.findByTestId(
      "save-update-program"
    );
    await user.click(saveUpdateProgramButton);
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(saveData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        title: "Test unit test",
        description: "Test description unit test",
        website: "website by unit test",
        twitter: "twitter by unit test",
      })
    );
  });
});

and here the jest setup file:
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => () => {
    const DynamicComponent = () => null;
    DynamicComponent.displayName = 'LoadableComponent';
    DynamicComponent.preload = jest.fn();
    return DynamicComponent;
});


any one can help?
